# Getting website source with C++ - content is repeated

Tags: c++

So, I have this source:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
 
using namespace std;
 
int main (){
        WSADATA wsaData;
 
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
                cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
                return 1;
    }
 
        SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
 
        struct hostent *host;
        host = gethostbyname("www.newegg.com");
 
        SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
        SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
        SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
 
        cout << "Connecting...\n";
        if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
                cout << "Could not connect";
                system("pause");
                return 1;
        }
        cout << "Connected.\n";
 
        send(Socket,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.newegg.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.newegg.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0);
        char buffer[10000];
 
        int nDataLength;
        while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,10000,0)) > 0){               
                int i = 0;
                while (buffer[i] || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
                        cout << buffer[i];
                        i += 1;
                }
        }
 
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
 
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Now, it works getting the source, however, it keeps repeating afterwards. For example:

[image]

Notice how it says , then continues? I was wondering how I can avoid that. I know I can limit the buffer, however is there a better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
    while (buffer[i] || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
    }
```

to

```
    for(; i != nDataLength; ++i)
            cout << buffer[i];
```

It looks like you are reading past the end of the buffer into garbage data used by `recv` and friends. Nobody said the data returned had to be null terminated which is what the while loop assumes for correct behavior.